# How to count a value in a specific row of an array with Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, artificial-intelligence

So basically I have an array, that consists of 14 rows and 426 Columns, every row represents one property of a dog and every column represents one dog, now I want to know how many dogs are ill, this property is represented by the 14. row. 0 = Healthy and 1 = ill, so how do I count the specific row?

I tried to use the `numpy.count_nonzero` but this counts the values of the entire array, is there a way to tell it to only count a specific row?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply sum the values of the 14.row and you get the number (count) of ill dogs:

```
count = A[13,:].sum() # number of ill dogs -- 13 because the index starts with 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have this vector:

```
>import numpy as np
>arr = np.arange(30).reshape(6,5)
>arr
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
       [25, 26, 27, 28, 29]])
```

With this, you will get the sum of all values for a specific row:

```
>np.sum(arr[1,:]) #On row 1
35
```

For your specific case, use:

```
>np.sum(arr[13,:])
```